# Extract partial string between two same characters with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have in cell `A1` the following value

```
Kate/Nancy/Judy
```

If I want to retrieve *Nancy* I need to use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("/" & A3&REPT(" ",6),"/",REPT(",",255)),2*255,255),",","")
```

What if I want to retrieve *Judy* or *Kate*? I cannot simply adjust `MID` to `LEFT` or `RIGHT` because these functions have different characteristics.

Thank you

Comment: could you please explain the reason of not using `MID`,`LEFT`,`RIGHT`

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(U20,"-",REPT(" ",100)),200,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with one formula, you could use:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/",REPT(" ",LEN($A2))),(B$1-1)*LEN($A2)+1,LEN($A2)))
```

Drag right and down.

More information about this formula can be found on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-with-delimiter) website.

We could also make use of VBA's [`SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function quite nicely, like so:

```
Function GetNth(Rng As String, Delmt As String, Nth As Long) As String
    Dim Arr() As String
    Arr() = Split(Rng, Delmt)
    GetNth = Arr(Nth - 1)
End Function
```

Call in your worksheet like: `=GetNth(A2,"/",1)`, `=GetNth(A2,"/",2)` or `=GetNth(A2,"/",3)` to return Kate, Nancy or Judy respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Select the data
2. Data tab - Data Tools - Text to Columns
3. Select Delimited - Next
4. Select Other and use "/" (without the double quotes) - Next - Finish

Results:

[image]